# Adding permanent items to Bootstrap 3 navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

The Bootstrap 3 navbar provides a header area and a collapsible area. The header area houses a branding link that is permanent and the collapsible area houses everything else that collapses under a hamburger icon when the window is shrunk. I am trying to add a select box and a button to the header area with the intent that they should be displayed permanently and not collapse when the window is shrunk. This is what I have tried so far (full code available in a [codepen here](http://codepen.io/nareshbhatia/pen/negbH))

```
<div class="navbar-header">
    <-- Hamburger button -->
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" ...>
        ...
    </button>

    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>

    <!-- Permanent select box -->
    <select class="navbar-text navbar-left">
        <option>Option 1</option>
        <option>Option 2</option>
    </select>

    <!-- Permanent button -->
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm navbar-btn navbar-left">
        Action
    </button>

</div>
```

Unfortunately I am seeing two problems:

1. The header wraps making the select box and the button fall below the brand link (you have to resize the window from small to big to see this effect).
2. Althought the button is specified as small, it shows up as big

Any idea how to solve these issues?

Comment: 1) How do you expect it to behave? if the window width is very small, it will be pushed down below the brand link.  2) You can change `btn-sm` to `btn-xs` if you need it to be smaller.

Comment: 1) Not too worried about very small window width. It is in the large window width where the items are being pushed below the brand link. To replicate this, you must shrink the window and expand it again. 2) btn-xs works perfectly - thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You could override the CSS and add this

```
.navbar-header{
  min-width: 275px;
}
```

2) You can change `btn-sm` to `btn-xs` if you need the button to be smaller.

**[See demo](http://codepen.io/blurfus/pen/kyeAc)**

Comment: This is perfect! Just curious why the header is wrapping even though I essentially floated left all three elements. Technically speaking the min-width should not be required, correct?

Comment: I am glad I could help.  I think it should not be required but... it may have something to do with media queries being applied to the hamburger section (for expanding-collapsing) but not the rest of the nav bar but I don't have the time to investigate further (sorry)